# Service Discovery and Service Proxy

Tags: proxy, microservices, service-discovery

If I use service-discovery, irrespective of doing client-side service discovery or server-side service discovery, where should I place the service proxy?

I know there are probably many ways to do this, but I'm having a hard time envisioning how to make all the pieces of the puzzle fit together.

I am supposing that somewhere I need to put an infrastructure piece that will control access to my APIs, and things like denial of service attacks, rate limiting, number of connections, header enforcement, authentication,  etc, need to be controlled by some sort of proxy or other infrastructure piece.

However, if all my calls pass through a proxy, then I have a hard time understating how service discovery is relevant. Is it the case that all my services will register themselves with the service registry always exposing the same address: that of my proxy?

Can somebody please enlighten me with some architectural ideas on how to deal with these aspects of the microservices design?